# One page won't load

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have ubuntu 13.04 and i have a problem loading just one page, every other work normally. 
The page is "moodle.pmfst.hr", i tried to open it in google chrome, firefox and opera but none would load it.
Page is working fine, because i asked my sister to try to load it and she said she have no problems with it.

I reinstalled java, installed nginx, MySQL, PHP. Reset Browser settings, enabel/disable cookies, enable/disable "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" But no help from that.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: The page http://znani.pmfst.hr/informatika1/ seems to indicate that you might need to log in some-how before you can access the page. I don't know **what** you need to do. But I **guess** this isn't a Ubuntu specific problem.

Comment: it shouldn't be "znani.pmfst.hr/informatika1", it stands for informatics and i need physics, i tried to change that last part but didn't work. There isn't any of my subjects at "znani.pmfst". it should be directly "moodle.pmfst.hr" but that seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

The domain resolves to 161.53.37.102 and this does not respond. I suggest this is a simple DNS misconfiguration.

The only problem with that as an answer is your sister. If it works there, there's either a difference in routing (a local static route) or there's a DNS override.

Comment: http://www.isup.me/moodle.pmfst.hr says it's not just me at least when I tested.

Comment: This page is for my college, professor gave it to us. I sent him an email, but i believe this page should work. Also, i asked mine classmates do they have similar problem and only one of them reply  that she do.

Comment: @shonjo I can only suggest you talk to your professor. There may be certain restrictions on the URL (eg, it may only work over an intranet) but whatever it is, it's not Ubuntu's fault.

Comment: Sure, i sent him an email yesterday, he didn't reply yet. anyway thanks for your help.